# How to add a custom dropdown menu in Magento2 to a PHTML template

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent

How can you add a custom dropdown menu in a Magento PHTML template?

So far, I've created the template in my theme and the markup is showing on the frontend.

This is the markup I'm using

```
<div class="actions dropdown example-dropdown-2">
    <button class="action toggle"
            data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true">
        <span>button + dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>
            <span class="item">One</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="item">Two</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="item">Three</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the drop down is not being initialized by javascript, it's just showing the normal HTML.  I thought `data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'` would initialise the dropdown widget but it doesn't.

Do I need to add a script, similar to how they have done in *app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml* with:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure what `"component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"` is for?

### UPDATE

I found I could add a tooltip with...

```
<div class="field-tooltip toggle">
    <span class="quick-menu about-dd"
          tabindex="0"
          data-toggle="dropdown"
          data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{"activeClass": "_active"}}'>About</span>
    <ul class="field-tooltip-content" data-target="dropdown">
        <li>
            <span class="item">One</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="item">Two</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="item">Three</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can't find anyway of doing the same to get a dropdown, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE June 2020

This answer is old and now Magento has better docs which describe how this can be done.

Please check: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_dropdown.html

---

In the end I got it working with the below:

```
<ul class="quick-links">
    <li class="links-container">
        <span data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}' data-toggle="dropdown">About</span>
        <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
            <ul class="header links">
                <li><a href="/contacts">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contacts">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contacts">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure why the example I gave in my question did not work as it's in all the answers on magento.stackexchange and is also what is outlined in the docs at *lib/web/css/docs/dropdowns.html*

The parent `li` of the dropdown link needs to have a class of `links-container` which I discovered just by looking through the Magento core by trial and error.

The dropdown menu opens on click only, next I would like to be able to change it to open on hover, I think I need to extend *lib/web/mage/dropdowns.js* for that.

### UPDATE

I figured out why it wasn't working with the example in the docs, it was just that the CSS wasn't added to the HTML class `example-dropdown-2` but the actual JavaScript is working.  If you look at the HTML in the browser inspector you can see that the class `active` is added to the `ul` etc.  For instance when you log in the the customer menu dropdown has this CSS

```
.customer-welcome .customer-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

And `.example-dropdown-2 .dropdown` does not. So you have to add your own CSS to hide & display the dropdown etc, or use the example I gave in my answer above which already has CSS if your theme inherits from the Luma them (maybe it's the same for the blank theme).

Shame, it's actually a really simple solution if the docs had been clearer it would have saved a lot of time.  Although I should have spotted why it wasn't working sooner.

Comment: This answer does not correctly explain an answer to the question you had.

Comment: fair point, It's an old answer.  I just updated it with the link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The widget is initialised correctly your missing `.lib-dropdown()` in your theme's less, in your example the minimum less would be

```
.example-dropdown-2 {
  .lib-dropdown();
}
```

Look at the docs on lib-dropdown for info on the paremeters, by default it generates css for the `.action.toggle` and `ul.dropdown` sibling classes as per your example html

Answer (score 0):

> **Add This code into your phtml file**

```
<ul>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <span
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              >
                        <a
                    class="action dwsswitch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You Menu Here')) ?></span>
            </a>
            </a>
        </span>
        <div  data-target="dropdown">
            <ul class="header links">
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
    .customer-welcome .action.dwsswitch:after {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: inherit;
    content: '\e622';
    font-family: 'luma-icons';
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    speak: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.customer-welcome.active .action.dwsswitch:after {
    content: '\e621';
}
</style>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***