# Magento 2 How to generate button dropdown

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, custom-button

I am new with Magento 2 and web development. I don't understand how to create dropdown button.
I saw some style in below website and I am not sure how to use it.

http://www.bergo.nl/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/dropdowns.html

I have button.phtml file in templates/product/view

And put the below code but It is not working.

```
<div class="example-dropdown-2">
<button class="action toggle"
        data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true">
    <span>button + dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li>
        <span class="item">One</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="item">Two</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="item">Three</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know how to add dropdown and what would be the best practice to implement?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to create a custom button in custom pages or want to replace everywhere in website please let me know some more details on this so that i can help you out

Comment: Thank you for replying! I want to add custom button in product screen. I already generate new template in layout file and connecting to "button.phtml" and this page, I can see product detail and "add cart" function button and I want to add custom button dropdown in button.phtml file

Comment: Please check following link it may help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167160/how-to-add-a-custom-dropdown-menu-in-magento2-to-a-phtml-template